# Nested Interface (empty) Dependency Registration

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dependency-injection

I have a parent interface that is empty, and its only purpose is to implement 2 other child interfaces. This way I can reduce the number of constructor parameters to an acceptable count. The problem is I dont know how to register this dependency in the container since there is no implementation of the parent Interface. Entries are present for the child services, but the dependent services are unable to find the required service dependencies for both children at this point.

```
services.AddScoped<IServiceChild1, IServiceChild1>();
services.AddScoped<IServiceChild2, IServiceChild2>();
// how to register IServiceParent

public interface IServiceParent: IServiceChild1, IServiceChild2
{
}
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what you hope to achieve by that? If there is no type that implements `IServiceParent` how you expect DI container to return something meaningful? Or you expect it to auto-generate proxy class that semi-randomly picks methods from some other registered implementations of child interfaces?

Comment: "This way I can reduce the number of constructor parameters to an acceptable count". This might be a bad idea. It seems that you are trying to treat the *symptoms* of [Constructor Over-Injection](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2018/08/27/on-constructor-over-injection/) instead of fixing the underlying cause, which likely is that those classes use too many dependencies and probably are too complex (might they violate the [SOLID](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SOLID_(object-oriented_design)) principles?). Try to find solutions that fix the underlying problems instead.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a class instead:

```
public class ServiceParentServices
{
    public IServiceChild1 Service1 { get; }
    public IServiceChild2 Service2 { get; }
    public class ServiceParentServices(IServiceChild1 service1, IServiceChild2 service2)
    {
        Service1 = service1;
        Service2 = service2;
    }
}
```

Register this class to the ServiceCollection, and when you want to consume it, just inject `ServiceParentServices` into the constructor

```
public class ServiceParent
{
    private ServiceParentServices _services;
    public ServiceParent(ServiceParentServices services)
    {
        _services = services;
    }
}
```

As an alternative you could also inject `IServiceProvider`, but this more like the ServiceLocator anti pattern.

Comment: Your answer is a great example of what I refer to in my comment on the question as "treating the symptoms", because, while `ServiceParentServices` reduces the number of constructor arguments of the consuming class, it doesn't lower the number of actual dependencies (and thus its complexity) of the consuming class. I would instead suggest refactorings such as the [Facade Service refactoring](https://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/02/RefactoringtoAggregateServices/) instead.